# Curried function type inference

Tags: typescript

I have the following wrapper function:

```
declare function wrap<A extends any[]>(fn: (...args: A) => (x: number) => number)
```

Instead of `number` there will be a generic `T` type, it's just a minimal example.

Now, when I use it and give types to outer arguments, TS incorrectly resolves `A` type. But if I leave at least one argument untyped, it resolves the type right.

```
wrap((a: number) => x => x) // Argument of type '(a: number) => (x: number) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => (x: number) => number'.
wrap(a => x => x) // OK
wrap((a: number, b) => x => x) // OK
```

However, if I use a little trick it will work again:

```
declare function id<T>(x: T): T

wrap((a: number) => id(x => x)) // OK
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwHcYoAHAHgEF4QAPDEVYAZ3ilQE8BtAXQD4AKRKgBc8fgDpJsAOZNRFAJTwAvLzE1RqZAFsARiBhLV8LXoMKAUBaKl+-KJp37DKtTVfwaSgPTf4FGGkdBgx4HER4DHYSBABye0czF2N+DRMncw9TZ1j4LBZUHFCoJiYsaVQoXQgEDBx4ElgobRB6GDCIqJj4eKM1VMTnPvSk2PFrYhJ7D3djL3hfeAB5AGkJ2wSR5wAaeF1h2bcfP1WrUEhYBBR0bDw84DIAFQE0x4VRR6sbKc3szOMsMBUjMFMdlisgA)

Why does this happen? Is it a TS limitation?

Comment: Seems like a bug to me. You should probably open an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues) to get some clarification on this.

Comment: Simultaneous inference of both type arguments and function parameters is always iffy.  In some of the places where you get "OK" things are inferred as `any` where you don't want them to be.  There are various github issues about related (but not identical) problems that are usually closed as "design limitation", like [ms/TS#46940](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46940). Not sure if pointing to such issues would constitute an answer in your opinion, or if you're looking for something official (in which case you can open an issue and post an answer here when it is triaged)

Comment: Oh, so it's a limitation. Then, I'll try to redesign my functions. I don't think it's worth to open an issue, as it could take a long time to resolve it. So, should I delete my question or leave it as is? I didn't find a close button.